# how to add Realloc

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I'm having trouble adding realloc to this array. I need to ask how many elements you want to add and then print the result, whenever I try something gives me error and then I don't know how I can do it.
I've searched a lot but I never find a correct answer that resembles what I need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    int total;
    int* pdados;
    printf("How many elements do you want ");
    scanf("%i", &total);
    pdados = (int *) malloc( total * sizeof(int) );
    if ( pdados == NULL ) {
        printf("error \n");
        return -1;
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < total; i++ ) {
        printf("%i valour: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%i", &padados[i]);
    }
    printf("the numbers entered were\n :");
    for ( int i = 0; i < total; i++ ) {
        printf(" %i", pdados[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    // ### realloc part realloc
    free( pdados );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] of the code that cause you problem, and tell us about the problems you have. For example, if you get build errors then copy-paste the full and complete build output (as text) into the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reallocate a dynamically allocated array then you shall not free the early allocated array. Otherwise all the current data of the array will be lost.

Let's assume that you need to add n new elements to an already allocated  array.

In this case you can write

```
int *tmp = realloc( pdados, ( n + total ) * sizeof( int ) );

if ( tmp === NULL )
{ 
    puts( "error" );
    free( pdados );
    return -1;
}

pdados = tmp;
total += n;
```

The newly added elements will be uninitialized. All other elements will keep their values.

Comment: I would suggest `sizeof(*tmp)`